# Hover even only triggered when the cursor moves in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover

How can I make sure that the `:hover` selector applies even if I refresh the page and don't move the cursor? I only have problems in Chrome. In works in Firefox.

Try the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sqrd2xgy/2/

In this demo, when I refresh the page the hover effect is not applied. So I have to move the cursor a bit.

[image: demo]

It looks like a common problem ([Chrome won't apply css hover style when left mouse button is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057499/chrome-wont-apply-css-hover-style-when-left-mouse-button-is-held-down)) so I wonder where there are any workarounds (pure css).

Comment: Did you try on Windows and Mac?

Comment: @makshh I'm using Mac

Comment: Viewing your demo on chrome, using Windows, it is working for me

Comment: I could provide a jQuery solution, but as far as I can see your current CSS is working on my end.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It works on Firefox but not Chrome. I can't test on other OSes than Mac right now.