# Why does CSS Transform not work when draggable = True?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am using internet explorer. I am trying to create a Drop Box that opens a lid when dragging some content over the box.  The onhover works nicely when moving the mouse over the Box.  However, when creating other Content, setting draggable = true, and then dragging the content over the box, the CSS and onhover fails to work.  I have googled this until I am green.  Any help would be appreciated.
Code is below:

```html
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }
    
            #DaBoxLid {
                background-color: saddlebrown;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100px;
                height: 40px;
                line-height: 40px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: 100px;
                -webkit-transition: transform 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
                transition: transform 2s, margin-bottom 2s, transform 2s;
            }
    
                #DaBoxLid:hover {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(25deg);
                    -o-transform: rotate(25deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(25deg);
                    transform: translateX(15px) translateY(-17px) rotate(25deg);
                }
    
            #DaBox {
                background-color: saddlebrown;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
                line-height: 50px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
    
            #Container {
                width: 1200px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
    
      
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
    
            <div id="Container">
                <div id="TheContent" draggable="true">Drag My Content</div>
                <div id="DaBoxLid">
                </div>
    
                <div id="DaBox">
                    My Drop Box
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome won't apply css hover style when left mouse button is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057499/chrome-wont-apply-css-hover-style-when-left-mouse-button-is-held-down)

Comment: Are you open to the idea of using JavaScript?